# codeigniter pagination displaying all records

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i do search all records are getting displaying and also pagination link is displaying in view page.

Also when i select the pagination link in an view page  empty record is getting displayed which is not in database.

Below is the controller

```
public function users() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $data1['showdata']=$this->searchmodelresult->login($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
    $count=$data1['showdata'];
    $totalrows=$count['count'];

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "search/users";
    $config["total_rows"] = $totalrows;
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->load->view('templatepages/searchresult',$data1,$result);
}
```

Below is the view page.

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

Comment: `print_r($data1['showdata'])` and check you getting correct data from DB

Comment: Can you post your view file?

Comment: add your model code

Comment: `if($this->uri->segment(3)){
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
}
else{
$page = 1;
}
$data1["results"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);` You should...

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL ya add please

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL You are doing wrong with pagination. will post correct one. wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - *Tested and working on mine*

> > Your URI segment will be 2 - `$config['uri_segment'] = 2;`

**In Controller**

```
$count = $this->searchmodelresult->get_count($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);

//product pagination
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'search/users';
$config['total_rows'] = $count;
$config['per_page'] = 2;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$limit = $config['per_page'];


$this->pagination->initialize($config);    
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$data['preview'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification, $limit,$page); # $limit and $page is added. 

$this->load->view('templatepages/searchresult',$data)
```

**In Model**

```
public function login($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification, $limit,$page)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * .... LIMIT $page, $limit");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}

public function get_count($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * .... ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' trying to solve this

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL any lunes??

Comment: Message: Undefined index: results
Filename: templatepages/searchresult.php

Comment: if (isset($showdata)){
           foreach ($showdata['results'] as $k => $result) 
    
   {  <?php echo $result['uid'];?> }

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: results

Comment: <?php
if (isset($preview)){
           foreach ($preview['results'] as $k => $result) 
    
   {
                ?>    <?php echo $result['uid'];?>     <?php }?>

Comment: ok solved it by removing results...but when i select page 2 numeric link same records are displaying instead which needs to change

Comment: getting this error from model page                                                        Error Number: 1327
Undeclared variable: users

Comment: <?php
if (isset($preview))
{
 foreach ($preview as $k => $result) 
{
                ?><?php echo $result['uid'];?>  <?php
            }
        }
  ?>                                                                                          <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>

Comment: so where is this error comes `Error Number: 1327 Undeclared variable: users`

Comment: echo "$page";   iam getting usesr

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL `print_r($data['preview'] )` and post data

Comment: $count = $this->searchmodelresult->get_count($look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'search/users';
$config['total_rows'] = $count;
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$limit = $config['per_page'];                                                               $this->pagination->initialize($config); if($this->uri->segment(3))
{ $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ; } 
else{ $page = 0; } 
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();$data['preview'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($look,as above $limit,$page);

Comment: ohhh ok...iam worried whom to accept ...wth all above efforts i solved the issue..

Comment: Thanks a lot ..thing i that i used every one support and at last able to solve it ..so accepting the all the answers

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL its ok. you can pick one answer. Choose whats helps you lot

Comment: @DHARAMKAMLEKARVISHAL happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
}
else{
$page = 1;
}
$data["results"] = $this->pagination_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
```

you can refer this link : https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: i used the form get link which you have given, but it shows all records .. kindly give me a solution